# How to determine what rectangle is on top?

Tags: java, swing, overlap, rectangles

I currently have a program that draws overlapping rectangles and was wondering if there is an easy way to determine which shape is on the top (most visible). This has me stumped as there is no z axis to use like in when dealing in 3D.

[image: overlapping rectangles]

I have tried looping through the rectangles and using the .contains method but it returns all rectangles under a specific point and not the highest level one.

I have also searched around but perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "most visible"? You mean the rectangle with the least amount of area that overlaps with other rectangles?

Comment: Presumably it is the last one you render

Comment: http://imgur.com/o4irIJl

In this case the lime green is on the "top." Not overlapped by another square?

Comment: I'm pretty sure lime green is on the "bottom."  Half-ripe lemon yellow is on top.

Comment: yeah i just realised iv used terrible colours, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when people do painting code they do something like:

List rectangles = ....

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++)
    //paint the rectangle
```

So if you want to search for a Point to determine what Rectanle it is in then you should use:

```
for (int i = rectangles.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{

    if (rectangles.get(i).contains(yourPoint))
    {
         // do something
         break;
    }
}
```

Starting from the end will give you the last rectangle painted which means it is on top of all aother rectangles.

Comment: Maybe this will explain a bit better what I'm trying to achieve?
http://imgur.com/icjVomN

I have the mouse listener working as intended and records where the user pressed x and y on the screen. From these co-ords how do I judge what is on the top?

Comment: I gave you the answer, just make sure the Point is the coordinates of the panel that you painted the rectangles on.

Comment: Ok will give it a try thanks. Sorry if this question came across as dumb but it is 4am :D

Comment: The question wasn't dumb, I'm just not sure why you didn't actually try out the suggestion. You already had looping code, which I just suggested you change the loop to go in reverse order. A one line change which you should have been able to do in a minute or so. Then either it worked (in which case you could go to bed) or it didn't (in which case you could ask for clarification). Don't be afraid to try things when you ask a question. Sometimes the suggestion will work, sometimes it won't either way you learned something by trying.

Comment: Im not too hot on 2D graphics and swing and for the solution to be that simple kinda took me by surprise. I have implemented your answer and it worked flawlessly. It also solved another issue inadvertently, where I was trying to clear the screen of rectangles. Seeing this solution made me realise I can just clear the arraylist of rectangles as the paintComponent method is simply going through the list and printing any rectangles contained. Thanks again!